# o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool : Unable to create initial connections of pool. Spring Boot + MySql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, mysql-workbench

I want to connect Spring boot application with database with help of MySql WorkBranch

```
o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.
```

is the exception i get

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.27</version>
        </dependency>
```

application.properties

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
#toa gore mora
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================

# Set here configurations for the database connection

# Connection url for the database "netgloo_blog"
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/OnlineBanking

# Username and secret
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password =

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=1

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager).

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

In MySql Workbranch server is set here is image:https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3G4s.png

I get this erros

```
2018-05-13 22:04:38.234 ERROR 6176 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
```

Can somebody help to connect spring boot with the database 
Thanks

Comment: Is everything correct at the mysql side? Can you connect using the mysql client to your database (mysql -u root -h dbhost OnlineBanking)? You might need to set a root password for the root@% user. (A username in mysql is always a combination of username + host, % = any in this case). Is the database on the same host as the application? If not, you need to set mysql config to listen to other ip besides 127.0.0.1 (=default) to enable remote networking to the db.

Comment: When i type mysql -u root -h hostname OnlineBanking i get error Host 'hostanme' is not allowed to connect to this MySql server, my bind-address is no default value so it probably should listen on all ports. Do you know how can i solve this Thank you very much @StijnHaezebrouck

Comment: See @Daniele 's answer how to correct this issue :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are in a development environment and security is not an issue for you, you can create a login by using the following SQL commands

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'*' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON * TO 'jeffrey'@'*';
```

See also

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html and
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html

Comment: And how can i connect with the user i created through the
application.properties and set these variables for the new created user ? spring.datasource.username= newuser
spring.datasource.password=newuserpassword 
Thank you @Daniele

Comment: Yes this was the answer Thank you very very much @Daniele

Comment: Uhm if you are using a spring-boot project then you would just edit your application.properties file? See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html